# IEnumerable.Except() on LINQ doesn't run between ideal source and target lists

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable, except

I start my question by mentioning this first - I have gone through the other SO questions and did end up into a situation/problem which I could not find myself an answer. So if there is, please point me to that.

My problem:
I have two lists of model objects.
Consider, I have a model class -

```cs
public class Contact 
{
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}
        public string MiddleName {get;set;}
        public long ContactId {get;set;}
        public long? DestKey {get;set;} 
}
```

And i have two data sources that may have some contacts data. Imagine, from Db source 1, I have 2 contacts and from Db Source 2, i have 10 contacts.

I am trying to find the unique contacts from Db1 list that are not on the Db2 list. I do use a custom Equality comparer to compare the data by checking the FirstName and Lastname fields. I did override the GetHashCode() as well.

So, my custom Equality Comparer looks like below:

```cs
public class MyContactComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contact>
{
        public bool Equals(Contact src, Contact dest)
        {
            // compare LastName
            if (!src.LastName.Equals(dest.LastName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) return false;

            // if LastName matches, compare FirstName
            if (!src.FirstName.Equals(dest.FirstName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                if (!(src.FirstName.Contains(dest.FirstName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || 
                    dest.FirstName.Contains(src.FirstName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
                return false;
            // do other needful comparisons
            //TODO: check for other comparison

            return true;

        }

        public int GetHashCode(MmdContact obj)
        {
            return obj.FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ obj.LastName.GetHashCode();
        }
}
```

and I call this by,

```cs
var nonMatchingContactsList = db2srcModelleddb1Data
                              .Except(db2ContactsData.ToArray(), new MyContactComparer())
                              .ToList()
                              .Select(person => person.ContactId);
```

Now, I have the data on Db1 set as

1. {FirstName = "Studo Mid", LastName = "Tar", MiddleName = null, ContactId = 1}
2. {FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar", MiddleName = "H", ContactId = 2}

Data on Db2 set as,

1. {FirstName = "Studo", MiddleName = "Mid", LastName = "Tar", DestKey = 10001}
2. {FirstName = "Studo", MiddleName = "Mid", LastName = "Tar", DestKey = 10002}
3. {FirstName = "Studo", MiddleName = "Mid", LastName = "Tar", DestKey = 10003}
4. {FirstName = "Studo", MiddleName = "Mid", LastName = "Tar", DestKey = 10004}
5. {FirstName = "Studo", MiddleName = "Mid", LastName = "Tar", DestKey = 10005}
6. {FirstName = "Studo", MiddleName = "Mid", LastName = "Tar", DestKey = 10006}
   ...
   and so on,
   by having duplicate records by names but having a unique DestKey. Assume, they were created by the logic that I explained below ending up in dups. Irrespective of that data quality fact, I'd expect the 2 contacts from Db1 set, be compared against the 10 contacts on Db2 set.

But when I debug this, the Equals() method is just iterating and checking between the 10 contacts of Db2 set as I could see the DestKey values between 'src' and 'Dest'. It seems to me that its comparing within the Db2 set and then identifying the 2 contacts on Db1 as not exists. So my logic goes and creates them, upon which, the "Studo Mid Tar" record is getting created again and again.

As and when I rerun again, it doesn't detect that contact as matching and doesn't do the Except() part. I'd say, the 2nd contact (Foo Bar) on the Db1 is something i'd like to see as the output to be created. The GetHashCode() is happening against the db2 sets only.

So, what is going wrong and why is this behavior?
What is needed to run this against the appropriate lists, i.e, 2 vs 10 records

UPDATE:
My primary question is lying around why the Equals() is comparing with its own list? Take a look at this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/upCgbb

I see the desired output but what i dont get it is, why the Equals() method compares the data of same Model type (in this case DataB) for few iterations instead of comparing A vs B? It does compares 1001 with 1002, then 1001 with 1003 before it is comparing with the actual A ContactId 1. Thats my question on why would it compare its own list?

Comment: First problem is that you're using a hash code implementation which is case-sensitive, but an equals implementation which is case-insensitive. The hash code and equality comparisons *must* be consistent. That may well be all that's wrong - I haven't looked in detail, and without a [mcve] to test and correct, it's hard to say more. If you can provide that complete example, it'll be easier to help you - but I would definitely encourage you to first fix the hash code computation.

Comment: Actually, the fact that you're using Contains in your Equals method makes it pretty unlikely that you'll end up fulfilling the Equals contract. For example, two objects with the same last name and first names of "a b" and "a" are equal. Likewise two objects with the same last name and first names of "a b" and "b" are equal. But two objects with the same last name and first names of "a" and "b" are *not* equal. You should only expect `Except` to work if you follow the rules for Equals and GetHashCode...

Comment: You are building your hashcode based on first and last names, while fist name is `"Studo Mid"` for first record in Db1 set and `"Studo"` for those in second. So you should end up with different hashcodes and zero matches.

Comment: I have added a dotnet fiddle for my query - https://dotnetfiddle.net/upCgbb. I see the desired output but what i dont get it is, why the Equals() method compares the data of same Model type (in this case DataB) for few iterations instead of comparing A vs B? It does compares 1001 with 1002, then 1001 with 1003 before it is comparing with the actual A ContactId 1. Thats my question on why would it compare its own list ...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare two lists and you have some kind of one-to-many relationship (one-to-none is also an one-to-many) or left-join you should use `.GroupJoin()`.

So if you replace your worker method with this:

```
public void DoMyWork()
{
    // expecting 1 record from A which is ContactId = 2 {Foo Bar}
    var nonMatchingContactsList = dataFromA
        .GroupJoin(
            dataFromB,
            a => $"{a.FirstName}|{a.LastName}",
            b => $"{b.FirstName} {b.MiddleName}|{b.LastName}",
            (a, matchingBs) => matchingBs.Any() ? null : a)
        .Where(a => a != null)
        .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine($"Total contacts specific to DbA: {nonMatchingContactsList.Count()}\r\n{string.Join("\n", nonMatchingContactsList)}");
}
```

You'll get your desired answer without usage of any self-written comparer. The *magic* happens within these lines:

```
a => $"{a.FirstName}|{a.LastName}"
```

This will create the desired key from your class. In my mental model this gets something like a `Dictionary<string, ModelA>`.

```
b => $"{b.FirstName} {b.MiddleName}|{b.LastName}"
```

This does the same for your second class and uses the needed properties to generate a similar key to make the comparison. Depending on your data you maybe have to improve this method to remove the space, if the middle name is null or empty.

```
(a, matchingBs) => matchingBs.Any() ? null : a
```

This is the result selector of the group join method. The first parameter is a modelA object and the second parameter is a list of all matching modelB objects. Because you like to get all ModelA objects where none matching objects exists in the ModelB list, we check `matchingBs.Any()` and if there is something matching, we return `null` otherwise `a`. Afterwards you simply have to throw away all the null values and you get the desired items from your ModelA list.

Maybe better method to avoid space if middle name is empty:

```
b => string.isNullOrEmpty(b.MiddleName)
     ? $"{b.FirstName}|{b.LastName}"
     : $"{b.FirstName} {b.MiddleName}|{b.LastName}"
```

One last tip about writing your own comparer class. There are a bunch of rules to respect, when implementing the methods `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`. To match them all, you should use this blue-print as a starting point and adopt to the properties that should be compared. By using this blue-print you avoid a lot of problems:

```
public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        return true;

    if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
        return false;

    if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        return false;

    if (x.MostDifferentialProperty != y.MostDifferentialProperty)
        return false;

    if (x.DifferentialProperty != y.DifferentialProperty)
        return false;

    // Other properties to compare...

    return true;
}

public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        return -1;

    // Add all properties from Equals() method here.
    return HashCode.Combine(obj.MostDifferentialProperty, obj.DifferentialProperty);
}
```